# How to close a process running in background indefinitely in a unix machine without pid?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, process, sqlplus

In a unix machine (solaris), after i entered user oracle like so:

```
su - oracle
```

I initiated a program via command line that does the following:

```
for i in $(seq 1 900); do while true ; do printf "select * from dual;\n" | sqlplus <user>/<password>; done &>/dev/null & done
```

I closed the terminal and the program keeps running in the background, as expected.

How do i terminate the program if i don't have the program pid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the PID of that job with `$!`, write it out into some file and access it there later.

Comment: I wish it was that simple, but that's not the answer i'm afraid, this is not the same session nor the same terminal, i am a few days later and from different machine

Comment: Yes I see you are creating 900 jobs. Question is why would you want to do this. Of course you then also have 900 PIDs to terminate. Another question is why are these queries running so long that you want to terminate them. Maybe you don't want to do it in parallel?

Comment: I was testing things, now all i want is to stop all them jobs, it's not 900 pids to terminate, because if i close 1 another one opens instead, that's not the way.

Comment: by the way, if i write the command "jobs" it doesn't give me anything...

Comment: As a last resort, if you have the `pkill` command, use:

    `pkill sqlplus`

Comment: "pkill -" is not helping either, Not owner fails are shown, and sqlplus still running

Comment: Then you are a different user and in this case you can't terminate the process. You have to terminate it as either the same user or as root.

Comment: Okay, so i'm root, what am i suppose to do there? pkill sqlplus? not doing anything

Answer (score 0):

To kill all processes with a command of `sqlplus`, try:

```
pkill sqlplus
```